# Hashmaps contain the same key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a

`Stack<MyThread> rts;`

each Thread contains a HashMap with a Custom Object Key.

`HashMap<CustomObject> myMap = rts.pop().mapOfThread;`

and I have the HashMap of these CustomObjectKeys

`MyThread.CustomObjectMap`

I need the fastest way to check if any of the HashMaps in the Threads in the Stack contains the same key as my CustomObject HashMap.

Comment: So presumably `Thread` here isn't `java.lang.Thread`? (Eek to start with - try to avoid reusing names that are already in `java.lang`.) It's then not clear how your second piece of code relates to this. Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - your question is very hard to understand at the moment.

Comment: I edited some changes for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you have a number of disjoint HashMaps that *may* share keys, and you want to see if any keys are the same across any **or** all?

If so, I don't really see a solution other than iterating through the `keySet()` and checking each HashMap to see if the key is present, probably via `containsKey()`.

Comment: There exists no "fast" solution for this?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, if you have to exhaustively search for each duplicate key in disjoint HashMaps. That is, I assume you have a "master" Map you iterate over to find keys that you then check each disjoint HashMap for equality. HashMaps are sort of tuned for finding values; it is merely a nice convenience that we have `containsKey()`, though it is probably going to be slower. At least you don't have to manually iterate through each HashMap separately. (If my assumption of this problem is correct, anyway.)

Comment: You could keep track of duplicate keys in a separate Collection (as their own values, or as a count, or...?); this is a classic time/space trade-off. That is, you use more space to keep track of keys in use, so later lookups are much faster.